# Find the flux of the vector field out of the region $T$ bounded by $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z = 4$. Please help

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the flux of the vector field $$\vec{F}(x,y,z)= <x,y,3>$$
out of the region $T$ bounded by $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z = 4$.

It says the unit vector $n$ is $<0,0,1>$, but how do you find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking how to find the unit vector? I expect by $(0,0,1)$, they mean the unit normal for the plane $z=4$, and we know that for any implicitly defined surface such as this, the gradient of the implicit defining function is normal to the surface. In this case, $\nabla(z-4)=(0,0,1)$. Seems we would then also consider the other part of the bounding surface, $x^2+y^2-z=0$, which has normal vector $\nabla(x^2+y^2-z)=(2x,2y,1)$. Divide by the magnitude to create a unit length vector.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Gauss divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)
$$\int_{S} \vec{F}.\hat{n} dS = \int_V \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F} dV$$
to simplify your computation.

> Note that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{F} = 2$. Hence, $$\int_{S} \vec{F}.\hat{n} dS = \int_V \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F} dV = 2 \int_V dV = 2\int_0^4 \pi z dz = \left. \pi z^2 \right \vert_0^4 = 16 \pi$$